# Trying to display 10 numbers per line from array

Tags: c++, arrays, infinite-loop

I am trying to display the all the numbers in the array but only 10 per line. When I run my code I am getting "168" in an infinite loop. Some help would be great I am really stuck.  Very new to C++ if it isn't obvious.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int number = 0;
int count = 0;
float average = 0;
int largest = -1;
int smallest = -1;
int *array;


cout << "Please enter a number between 20 and 100: ";
cin >> number;

if (number >= 20 && number <= 100)
{
    int k = 0;
    array = new int[number];
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    int random;
    for (int index = 0; index < number; index++)
    {
        random = (rand() % 1000) + 1;
        array[k] = random; k++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000;)
    {
        cout << array[i] << "";
        if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0)
        {
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "The number must be between 20 and 100. \n";
    cout << "Please enter a number between 20 and 100: " << endl;
    cin >> number;
}
system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Also, you should [explain your code, line by line, to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). I bet a 100 quatloos that your rubber duck knows why your code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look at this loop: `for (int i = 0; i < 1000;)` Which part is it missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have undefined behaviour.

`number` is between 20 and 100, inclusive.

You use it as the size when you allocate `array`.

You then run a loop range [0,1000), which uses `i` to index way past the end of that array.

Comment: No, but only because that loop never increments.

Answer (score 0):

You run into an infinite loop due to the following line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000;)
```

This is missing the increment expression, as a result of which the conditional expression `(i < 1000)` always (a.k.a infinitely) stays true.

Comment: On a side note: Your variable `k` here seems redundant and duplicates the `index` variable. You might want to consider using the `index` variable itself, and get rid of `k` to keep your code simple and concise.